# PHP syntax for opening a new tab on click

Tags: php, echo, href

I need to add `target="_blank"` property somewhere so that when logos are clicked they are opened in a new tab.

I am working on a website that uses the following PHP code to reference links in logos:

```
<?php if($cta): ?>
    <div class="product-logos-container">
        <?php foreach($cta as $_cta): ?>
            <span class="card" <?php if($_cta['banner_link']): ?>onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $_cta['banner_link'] ?>'"<?php endif ?>>
                <span class="detail" style="opacity: 0;">
                    <span class="inner"><?php echo $_cta['banner_title'] ?></span>
                </span>
                <img src="/clear_cta/<?php echo $_cta['banner_filename'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $_cta['banner_title'] ?>" class="image"/>
            ......
```

Now I'm fairly certain that I need to add `target="_blank"` to the 4th line. I'm not sure which syntax is right for it, and after doing some research I'm starting to think that `window.location` might be the problem. If so please advise an alternative code that would open links when clicked in new tabs.

Comment: `target` is not permitted on `<span>` elements. If you need to open the window in a new tab, use the `window.open()` method in JS.

Comment: Use `<a target="_blank"` instead and additionally use CSS to make it looking as you want if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.open instead of window.location

```
window.open('<?php echo $_cta['banner_link'] ?>',
'_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their contribution. This here worked flawlessly for me. 

Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Only we can use `target="_blank"` inside anchor tags () to tell the browser where the linked document should be loaded.

**Try This**

1

```
<span>
    <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">See my portfolio</a>
</span>
```

2

```
 <a target = '_blank' href=view_rfp_detail.php?sna=$sna >$sna</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your case this is more of a JavaSript problem. The important part is

`window.location.href=something`

It is very complicated to open a new window or tab from JavaScript. This is the infamous popup. The browser started to block it by default long time ago.

You can try to rewrite this part

```
<span class="card" <?php if($_cta['banner_link']): ?>onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $_cta['banner_link'] ?>'"<?php endif ?>>?>onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $_cta['banner_link'] ?>'"<?php endif ?>>
```

Into something like

```
<a class="card" <?php if($_cta['banner_link']): ?>href="<?php echo $_cta['banner_link'] ?>" target="_blank"<?php endif ?>>
```

and change the closing tag too.